# how to customize default messaging application in android

Tags: android

I am newbie in android. I am developing an application in which we have to authenticate default message box provided by android OS. In that a user should unable view received messages without credentials. I.e. we have to launch own activity after the user clicks on the message box.

I have tried a lot but not getting proper way ..

Is it possible in android ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: what message box are you talking about? Which received messages? Do you mean text messages(SMS)?

Comment: Yeah,text messages(SMS) ... i want to authenticate sms box before user viewing incoming message